# Reading Strings.xml file from apk file

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there any way you can read the `strings.xml` file from an `apk file`?
I am not interested in libs or classes/code file just the strings defined in `strings.xml`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes you can extract all the Resource files using [`apktool`](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)

Steps -

```
1.) Download files from above links and extract them in a folder.
2.) Open cmd -> run 
3.) Run command as 
    apktool.bat d source.apk destination_path
```

OR

```
1.) Put apktool.jar and test.apk in same folder 
2.) Go to the jar and .apk path by command line
3.) And fire the command java -jar apktool.jar d test.apk
4.) It will generate a folder with the name "test" in the same folder.
```

Comment: Good Work bro..Cheers..One more Question..:))...Is it possible to extract the src folder of our Android project..is there any tool that would do this.??

Comment: Oh!!! yes you can [extract src folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/726863) also, but it won't be completely readable, but almost you can get the idea what the code is all about :)

Comment: @LalitPoptani the apktoll isn't available on the link you've provided.

Comment: Man you are a life saver... Thank you so much!

Comment: I would like to add that  after extraction from apktool, string.xml file can be located in destination_path/res/values/ folder.

Answer (score 8):

Download [android-apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) (download dependencies also if required), extract all in the same directory and run `apktool d application.apk`

Answer (score 3):

Download [apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/)

1. Put apk file ( suppose test.apk ) in the directory where you have downloaded it.
2. Now type the command ' apktool d test.apk '
3. Now browse to " test \ res \ values "

You will get your strings.XML file there.

Answer (score 3):

Another option besides `apktool` is `aapt`, but it won't reproduce the strings in the original XML form.

```
$ aapt dump --values resources app.apk |
  grep '^ *resource.*:string/' --after-context=1

  resource 0x7f04011a com.example:string/hello: t=0x03 d=0x0000039e (s=0x0008 r=0x00)
    (string8) "Hello"
  ...
```

Comment: is there a way to only get the english strings?